# NoMethodError although method is defined in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I am having a small problem with a method in Ruby. "information" is a hash that I want to iterate through, format the value if necessary and save a new hash with the formatted/changed pairs. The following:

```
formatted_information = {}     

information.each do |key, value|
  formatted_information[:"#{key}"] = self.send("format_#{key}(#{value})")
end
```

is supposed to call another method in the same document that handles the formatting (so if the key "name" was found it should run "format_name" with the corresponding value). Although the method exists I get the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `format_name("Some Name")'

What mistake am I making here?

Possible input:
information = {:name => "A Name"}

Expected output:
formatted_information = {:name => "B Name"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send` accepts the method name as the first argument, and the arguments to that method as the second argument. You should use

`send("format_#{key}", value)`